# Successful postdoc interview at an Italian institution in December by a UK citizen. Would the EU-UK trade deal have an impact on my chances?

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom, italy, eu

I am a UK citizen and obtained my PhD at a UK university in August. I was shortlisted for a postdoctoral position at an Italian institution in mid December before the UK-EU trade deal was made. The interview went amazingly well and I was given a very positive feedback for my performance. Of course, the procedure was halted due to the Christmas holidays. In the new year the new EU-UK trade deal was agreed upon and I am no longer sure what my position is. I was confident of an offer, but now I am concerned I would need sponsorship, as a result of said trade deal, and fear that potential offers would be retracted.

I would be grateful for someone with more experience on this matter to shed some light on my concerns. I have read the documents in which they state the conditions for non-EU citizens, but the document was not very helpful or informative and seemed rather vague.

Comment: It isn't like Brexit was unexpected by the Italians. Likely they also hire non-EU postdocs. So, they will process the necessary paperwork.

Comment: You need to ask the Italian institution. Ask if there are additional complications and what you can do to resolve them.

Comment: Which kind of postdoc is it? Is it an RTD-A position or an _assegno di ricerca_?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano it is Assegno di ricerca

Comment: @Carl Looking at the regulation for the calls in my university, which is probably common to other universities as well, I wouldn't expect any issue.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano thank you ever so much. This is such a relief.

Comment: Solidarity from another UK -> EU PhD -> postdoc transitioner! In my opinion the deal has actually made things better, as now I and my new employer have a better idea of what visa is needed so I think you should be fine.

Comment: My experience with the Italian system is that they are keen on hiring native English speakers and they are very keen to help with all kinds of potential issues that could come up. There are not so many researchers from abroad coming to Italy, and they feel honoured by everyone who does it. Even if there is some additional paperwork required, I'd expect that they will help you with it or even do it for you.